# Change color of NavigationView's divider and deactive itemiconTint attributte

Tags: android, navigationview

I have manage to show divider in navigation view using different group id as mentioned in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625280/how-to-create-a-simple-divider-in-the-new-navigationview) question. but i want to know how to change the color of the divider and deactive itemiconTint attributte. Thank in advance

---

EDIT: I ask question in comment and @Moinkhan has answer it. so i edit this question

Comment: refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730819/how-can-i-change-separator-color-in-navigationview

Comment: thats my answer bro you can vote up there .. lolzz...

Comment: @Moinkhan can you help me how to deactive attribute android.support.design:itemIconTint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can deactive tint using

**Programmatically**

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

**Using XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

I hope it helps you ..

Comment: i try tu use xml to deactive itemicontint attribute but it didnt work, but the programmatically way works like charm. Thank you

Comment: And u knw its good that you have changed the question which avoid people to get confuse ..keep it up bro

Comment: is it possible to remove the icon tints for individual items?