# How to remove line in navigation view between groups

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library

I have a navigation view in android and I want to remove lines between groups, but I cannot figure out anything and could not find any solution, how can I manage this ? thank you

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/car"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="@string/main"/>
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:title="@string/hef">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:checkable="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/store"
                android:id="@+id/storeItem"
                android:title="@string/store"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line in your style file. Use this in your main style eg-> AppStyle

**`<item name="android:listDivider"> @android:color/transparent </item>`**

**you can refer my this answer also**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731387/3544839

Comment: That's not the standard way. You must not change divider style throughout the app.