# View divider is not visible in my Android Navigation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, android-navigationview

here is my menu for navigation view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_main"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/my_quote"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_myquote"
            android:title="@string/my_quote" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/hotels"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_hotel"
            android:title="@string/hotels" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/attractions"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_attraction"
            android:title="@string/attractions" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tour_packages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_package"
            android:title="@string/tour_packages" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/restaurants"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_rest"
            android:title="@string/restaurants" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/transport"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_transport"
            android:title="@string/transport" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/tour_guides"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_guide"
            android:title="@string/tour_guides" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_settings"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="@string/settings" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

View setup:

```
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.side_menu);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Result:

[image]

Using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'` (the same with 23.0.1)
Why there is no divider? Maybe it is white but how can I change it?

Comment: @Androider i need to use divider between groups only

Comment: to change the color go for it .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30731387/3544839

Comment: @Moinkhan please be more attentive, this answer is already posted

Answer (score 1):

just apply following line on style.xml
`<item name="android:listDivider">your_color</item>`

and use in frame layout as 
`

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

`

Comment: I tried to add this attribute to `NavigationView` but it's not working. Where should I apply it?

Comment: add in style.xml 
<item name="android:listDivider">your_color</item>, 
it should work, alternatively add blank header as separator.

<group android:id="@+id/my_id">
    <!-- Divider will appear above this item -->
    <item ... />
</group>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the best solution. But at least for me this solution works without using a divider View.

Add `menuCategory` attribute to your second `group` and set it `secondary` . For example:

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_settings"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:menuCategory="secondary">
```

Comment: doesn't help unfortunately