# remove line divider from NavigationView android

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

i have this menu for the NavigationView of layout:

```
<item android:title="title1">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tab1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_nav_tab1"
            android:title="test1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tab2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_nav_tab2"
            android:title="test2" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="title2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:title="test3" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

[image]

how can remove the line divider from menu?

Comment: Try to remove ID's from your items.

Comment: @Stanojkovic thanks for comment. but without id how can access  item in app? i just need to remove the divider.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your `Styles`:

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Here you can read more about it: 
[How can I change separator color in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730819/how-can-i-change-separator-color-in-navigationview/30731387#30731387)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with BottomNavigationView. Maybe someone will find my solution usefull.

Reason of this divider on android devices with API < 21 is this code snippet in BottomNavigationView sources:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    this.addCompatibilityTopDivider(context);
}
```

addCompatibilityTopDivider(context) method:

```
private void addCompatibilityTopDivider(Context context) {
    View divider = new View(context);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color.design_bottom_navigation_shadow_color));
    LayoutParams dividerParams = new LayoutParams(-1, this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimen.design_bottom_navigation_shadow_height));
    divider.setLayoutParams(dividerParams);
    this.addView(divider);
}
```

My solution was to override `design_bottom_navigation_shadow_color` in `colors.xml`, like this:

```
<color name="design_bottom_navigation_shadow_color" tools:override="true">#00000000</color>
```

And it works:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<group android:id="@+id/menu_top">
<item android:title="title1">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tab1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_nav_tab1"
            android:title="test1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tab2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_nav_tab2"
            android:title="test2" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="title2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:title="test3" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Try grouping these items...I haven't tried this but it should work

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need to remove the divider. your solution keep that line.