# How to draw a line between menu item in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-menu

I want to highlight navigation items like this:

[image: highlighted item in navigation menu]

But my current menu looks like this:

[image: not highlighted item in navigation menu]

My menu.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home_page"/></group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/p_profile"
            android:title="Payment Profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_payment_profile"/></group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/p_history"
            android:title="Payment history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_payment_history"/></group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/m_cards"
            android:title="My cards"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_my_card"/></group>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_friends"
                android:title="Friends"
                android:icon="@drawable/search_people"/></group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:title="Notification"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_notification"/></group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/about"
            android:title="About"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about_us"/></group>

    </group>
</menu>
```

How can I create the above highlight effect?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it man?

Comment: Nop  it gives black line in black background . I need to make white line whats may the solution ?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the question where it's explained how to change the color. I've managed to help you put the line there, now just apply this and it'll work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Give each group a unique id like this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
android:id="@+id/group1">
```

It'll draw those lines for you between any two groups.

**EDIT**: Since the line is now showing but it's black on the black background, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730819/how-can-i-change-separator-color-in-navigationview) to see how to change the color of the divider.