# android - listDivider not showing in BottomSheet

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have implemented in my app a BottomSheetDrawer as a navigation menu.

I have separated the menu items accordingly with a group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/ndGroupOthers" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ndListFolder"
            android:title="Folders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_folder_24" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/ndGroupInfo" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ndListSettings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24px" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/ndListAbout"
            android:title="About"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_24px" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

...however, the listDivider won't show in my compiled app.

**Images**

[image: Screenshot from phone]

Screenshot was taken on a phone

[image: Android Studio preview]

Android Studio Preview

I already added `android:listDivider` as an item in the app's style, in fact, the divider shows up, if I use a normal NavigationDrawer, and it shows up if I load the bottom sheet fragment from the MainActivity.kt.

I assume this is a problem related to the fact that the BottomSheetDrawer getting loaded from the BottomSheet class.

Is there a way I can fix this, maybe programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried changing the divider color?, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38366378/8244632).

Comment: Wow! Didnt expected this to be just a theme issue, creating a separate style works! Post this as answer so i can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glat it worked but answers which already exist here shouldn't be posted again until and unless they're more detailed than previous one. I'd suggest searching things first because as I've experienced there's rarely something you can't achieve with the existing resources, you just have to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Yes, it did answer my question. Apologies for the duplicate question.